# How to run a script on resume to restart the audio drivers?

Tags: ubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa, sleep

I'm currently running "Linux grant-N501VW 4.10.0-40-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 9 14:49:09 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux" and I always get white noise through the headphones after resuming the machine. I discovered the command to do this:

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```

but I would like it to run automatically on resume. However, it is a little finniky as usually the first time I run it after resume it prints out this and doesn't fix the issue:

```
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-seq snd-rawmidi snd-seq-device 
snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec 
snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer 
(failed: modules still loaded: snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic 
snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-seq snd-rawmidi snd-seq-device 
snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec 
snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer.
```

However, after running the failed command, if I run it again it prints out:

```
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hda-intel snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event 
snd-seq snd-rawmidi snd-seq-device snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic 
snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer.
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hda-intel snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event 
snd-seq snd-rawmidi snd-seq-device snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek 
snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer.
```

and the audio white noise is fixed. I've looked into creating a script in /etc/pm/sleep.d/ but that hasn't seemed to work.